# Different change lists in subclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

In IntelliJ, I can have different change lists so that I can put certain files that I never want to commit into a different change list, and I won't be prompted to commit those files unless I select that change list. For example, certain database configuration files, eclipse project files etc., I want to rarely or never commit.

Is there a way to do this using Subversion in Eclipse? I haven't been able to find it so I have to uncheck the files I don't want to commit every time. Note that I can't use svn:ignore because these files are, and should be, in the repository.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do this in the *Synchronize* view. Click the *Show Change Sets* button. You can then add changed files to change sets (and create new change sets) from the right-click menu.

Comment: Wonderful! Been missing this a lot from IntelliJ :)

Comment: and the changesets will only show up after you set some file to some changeset.

Answer (score 6):

While the notion of change set of change list is not *directly* supported by subversion, one possibility would be to use SVN in conjunction with [**Mylyn**](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/).

You could set each group of files to a different *task* and see if subclipse allows you to commit only one or several tasks through Mylyn.
I have not tested that configuration directly, but it is worth a try.

An option like (see [Mylyn Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Team)):

> **Automatically create and manage with task context** - Enables automatic change set management. Change sets will be created automatically so that you can commit or update only resources that are in a task's context.

sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

Change Sets in eclipse (subclipse plugin) does not work too well. If you close the project and reopen it, then either your change sets disappear or all the files you've previously assigned to a change set are now unassigned. SVN:ignore does not work if it happens to be a directory but you want to track files which inside the directory (don't ask how this happens - difficult to explain). IntelliJ change list is much better.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting those files on svn:ignore list? 
(set the files to exclude as values of 
 svn:ignore property)
They will be just excluded from versioning so that they never get 
 
commited and any changes to these files will be ignored by subversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the TeamCity plugin you can have a more advanced Synchronize view than normal in eclipse.
Or just keep using IDEA......