# Mark files to be committed at project completion?

Tags: eclipse, svn, project-management, subclipse

Recently I've found myself working on fixes / new projects for my companies program that span across multiple files (as a proper code structure should). As I'm nearing completion of a project, which may have taken me a while to finish due to being pulled away with other tasks and what not, I find myself stressing over remembering what files I've touched for which project and what I need to commit at the completion of the job.

As I do many times while working I find myself thinking, there *has* to be a better way.

I'm working in Java on Eclipse and we use Subclipse to work with our SVN. Does anyone know of another tool or some other way that I can keep track of files to commit on a per job basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280451/different-change-lists-in-subclipse) which I think the synchronized view is what I need.

**Edit:**

After even more searching I found [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) which works well for me since I can activate a task and have it keep track of everything that I look at / change.

Works really well.

Answer (score 1):

[changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html) might be able to relate your changes to issues/jobs your working on.