# Mark files before committing to SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

Each time before committing I have a lot of changed files in my project. But also I have a lot of files that shouldn't be committed to SVN (it need me for local work). I need traverse all changed files and **REMEMBER** which of them should be committed.
 Is that possible to mark(maybe with some Eclipse plugin) files for further selection and committing.

Comment: Right answer is change lists -- NOT IGNORE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html). See this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280451/different-change-lists-in-subclipse) on using changelists in Eclipse.

In Subversion 1.5 and higher, you can put your files into changelists. You can then commit, update, and revert only those files in that particular changelist. Put your "don't commit files" into one changelist, or the "I only want to check in these files into another changelist.

The `svn:ignore` won't work if these files are already checked into Subversion. It's only for adding *new* files.