# Create Eclipse SVN "virtual branches"?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, version-control, subclipse

I program Java using Eclipse and SVN in my company and one of the commit rules it's that each commit have their own purpose, and it's always one.

Sometimes I can get some work done but can't publish it on the server until the end of the day (it will break the build) and then I have to do some other work (non related to the first) and commit it, but if I do that I'm commiting changes related to 2 tasks.

What I want here it's to have a way to say to Eclipse that I want to separate those changes and on both of the tasks I want to work with the trunk code. So, basically it's a branch, but that never existed, in order to let me make separate commits. I thought about having N eclipse workspaces working with the trunk code and use each onde for each change, but that seems overkilling.

Is it doable?

Comment: You basically want Git implemented on SVN. A tough call... there are some git-to-svn bridges that may help, but I'm not swearing by them.

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij you have changelists that you can commit separately. Maybe this question can help you further on your way: [Changelists in subclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280451/different-change-lists-in-subclipse)

Comment: What if there's two (or more) changes in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing it so that you can make two different sets of changes within a single file is to `checkout` a second working copy for the second tasks set of changes, and work on those independently. When either task is complete you can commit the changes made in that working copy, and update the other working copy before committing that once it builds.